# failed to read row 0,column -1

Tags: android, sqlite

I am trying to copy a database that I made with SQLite manager, in which I did:

```
CREATE TABLE "android_metadata" ("locale" TEXT DEFAULT 'en_US')
```

and

```
INSERT INTO "android_metadata" VALUES ('en_US')
```

And I named all my primary keys `_id`. My database gets copied(in the first run there are various red messages in the logcat); thereafter, it only gives an error when I query it.

**MainActivity**

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
String CNAME=" ques",TABLE_NAME=" JAVAQ";




@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Setupdb dbobj=new Setupdb(this); 

    try {    

        //dbobj.close();
        dbobj.createDataBase();

    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } 



    dbobj.openDataBase();
    dbobj.close();



   try{
         SQLiteDatabase sqdb=dbobj.getReadableDatabase();



         Cursor c = sqdb.query(TABLE_NAME,
                 new String[] { CNAME },
                 null, null, null, null, null); 
         while (c.moveToNext()) {

            String name =
            c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(CNAME));
            Log.i("LOG_TAG", " HAS NAME " + name);
         }}



            catch(Exception e){

                Log.e("err", e.toString());
            } 




}}
```

**Setupdb**

```
public class Setupdb extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

  private static String DB_PATH = "";
    private static final String DB_NAME = "camprep.sqlite";
    private SQLiteDatabase myDataBase;
    private final Context myContext;

    private static Setupdb mDBConnection;


public Setupdb(Context context) {
    super(context, DB_NAME, null, 3);
    this.myContext=context;
    DB_PATH="/data/data/"
            + context.getApplicationContext().getPackageName()
            + "/databases/";
    Log.e(DB_NAME, DB_PATH);
}
public static synchronized Setupdb getDBAdapterInstance(Context context) {
    if (mDBConnection == null) {
        mDBConnection = new Setupdb(context);
    }
    return mDBConnection;
} 

    public void createDataBase() throws IOException {

        boolean dbExist = checkDataBase();
        if (dbExist) {
            Log.e("db","exist");
            // do nothing - database already exist
        } else {
            // By calling following method
            // 1) an empty database will be created into the default system path of your application
            // 2) than we overwrite that database with our database.
            this.getReadableDatabase();
            try {
                Log.e("calling", "copy");
                copyDataBase(); 
            } catch (IOException e) {
                throw new Error("Error copying database");
            }
        }





}
    private boolean checkDataBase() {
        SQLiteDatabase checkDB = null;
        try {
            String myPath = DB_PATH + DB_NAME;
            checkDB = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(myPath, null,
                    SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READONLY);

        } catch (SQLiteException e) {
            // database does't exist yet.
        }
        if (checkDB != null) {
            checkDB.close();
        }
        return checkDB != null ? true : false; 
    }

    private void copyDataBase() throws IOException {
        // Open your local db as the input stream
    InputStream myInput = myContext.getAssets().open(DB_NAME);
        // Path to the just created empty db
    String outFileName = DB_PATH + DB_NAME; 
        // Open the empty db as the output stream
    OutputStream myOutput = new FileOutputStream(outFileName);
        // transfer bytes from the inputfile to the outputfile
    byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
    int length;
    while ((length = myInput.read(buffer)) > 0) {
        myOutput.write(buffer, 0, length);
    }
        // Close the streams
    myOutput.flush();
    myOutput.close();
    myInput.close();
}


    public void openDataBase() throws SQLException {
        String myPath = DB_PATH + DB_NAME;
        myDataBase = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(myPath, null, SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READWRITE);
    }
    public synchronized void close() {
        if (myDataBase != null)
            myDataBase.close();
        super.close();
    } 

@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {


}

}
```

**Stacktrace**

```
 08-31 20:17:05.320: I/dalvikvm(9457): threadid=3: reacting to signal 3
08-31 20:17:05.370: I/dalvikvm(9457): Wrote stack traces to '/data/anr/traces.txt'
08-31 20:17:05.451: E/camprep.sqlite(9457): /data/data/com.example.mydataexplosion/databases/
08-31 20:17:05.490: E/db(9457): exist
08-31 20:17:05.521: E/CursorWindow(9457): Failed to read row 0, column -1 from a CursorWindow which has 11 rows, 1 columns.
08-31 20:17:05.521: E/err(9457): java.lang.IllegalStateException: Couldn't read row 0, col -1 from CursorWindow.  Make sure the Cursor is initialized correctly before accessing data from it.
08-31 20:17:05.650: D/gralloc_goldfish(9457): Emulator without GPU emulation detected.
08-31 20:17:05.650: I/dalvikvm(9457): threadid=3: reacting to signal 3
08-31 20:17:05.670: I/dalvikvm(9457): Wrote stack traces to '/data/anr/traces.txt'
```

Answer (score 48, accepted):

if you see

```
failed to read row 0,column -1
```

It means you are  trying to read from a column which doesn't exist.

If it cannot find the column name that you specify, `Cursor.getColumnIndex()` returns `-1` and hence, is invalid.

There are two reasons for this:

1. **The column does not exist.**
2. **The name of the column is incorrect.** (so does not exist).

Note: the name of the column is **CASE SENSITIVE** when using `getColumnIndex()`

---

In your scenario:

```
 c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(CNAME));
```

Check that the CNAME variable is spelt correctly, and that a column of that name exists.

```
String CNAME=" ques"
```

Should that extra leading white space be there for example..

Comment: yes it works now, but should i worry as it gives error messages in the logcat at the first run.

Comment: @dreamer1989 You should worry depending on the content of the error messages in the logcat.  Either way, asking if the error messages are worrisome or not make an excellent _second question_.  Don't make this question do double duty.

Comment: Yes you are absolutely right and that type of error spoiled our time for overthinking

Answer (score 1):

Before you start reading the consecutive values by using  `c.moveToNext()` , set the cursor to the initial position, that is the beginning of your database.

**`c.moveToFirst()`**

and then start reading form it.

Might solve your problem.

Comment: I disagree. There is no requirement to use `moveToFirst()` before `moveToNext()`. If you have a new cursor that is at index -1, `moveToNext()` will move the index to 0 and return true (if there is at least one row).

Comment: @Sam : Yes sir, I do totally agree with you! But there was no other reason I could find in his code which would have taken the cursor to -1 position and hence gave my views on it. Your logic is correct, but then why the error **only** during the first run ? It was the comment about errors on the first run which made me think of this. Also notice the use of the word **"might"** in my answer, as I am no master in SQLite and cursors. :)

Comment: I understand your logic, but take a closer look at the error: `Failed to read row 0, column -1`. The column index is `-1` not the row index.

Answer (score 0):

The mistake was using umlauts ü,ö,ä in the database column names.

Although you can get the content by switching with the method `cursor.movetonext()` so often until you moved to the right number, it was very annoying and requested a bunch of code.

I guess this should solve the problems for most of you. I guess anything but ASCII is wrong -- spaces, dots, minuses etc., cannot be used either.

You may successfully create a database and you may can see with external sqlite tools but android will always nag.

Answer (score 0):

Another Scenario when this can happen:
**You are deleting rows from the cursor while the cursor is still in use.**

E.g pseudo-coden where it could happen:

```
while(cursor.moveToNext()){

  readCursor(cursor);

  deleteRowFromCursor(cursor);

}
```

**Solution:**

Keep list of rows you want to delete; build a batch delete sql statement; execute the statment out side of the while loop ( when you are done with using the cursor anymore or after you close it).

```
while(cursor.moveToNext()){

  readCursor(cursor);

  queueRowForDelete(cursor);

} 

deleteQueuedRows(queuedRowsList);
```