# Couldn't read row 0, col -1 from CursorWindow

Tags: android, cursor, android-sqlite

I'm trying to get records in my table. I'm using this code

```
        if(c!=null){
            if(c.moveToFirst()) {

                String tipId = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(DAO.TIP_ID)).toString().trim();                 
                System.out.println("tipId: "+ tipId);

            }else{
                // Handle no rows returned
                System.out.println("Handle no rows returned");
            }
        }else{
            System.out.println("debug Cursor , cannot be created");
        }
```

But it gives me the following exception

```
Couldn't read row 0, col -1 from CursorWindow.  Make sure the Cursor is initialized correctly before accessing data from it.
```

and it refers to that line:

```
String tipId = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(DAO.TIP_ID)).toString().trim();
```

hope anyone helps me to fix this. 
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your code

```
  c.getColumnIndex(DAO.TIP_ID)
```

**is returning -1**. This means value of  **DAO.TIP_ID** doesnot match with any column name of table .Check if this value is correct and matches with a column name of the table you are accessing

add following line before the line which causes problem and post the Logcat output here

```
 Log.v("out-data",DAO.TIP_ID+" "+c.getColumnIndex(DAO.TIP_ID)+" "+c.getColumnName(0));
```

(add import statement **import android.util.Log;** in beginning of your 
code)

Comment: The value of DAO.TIP_ID is (_id) and the column name is (_id) too. I copied the name. :(

Comment: I have edited the answer .Do the changes and post logcat output here

Comment: Also post your select query

Comment: As suggested, the name does not match a valid column. Triple check for spelling mistakes, and whitespace. [failed to read row 0,column -1](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12222141/failed-to-read-row-0-column-1/12222190#12222190)

Comment: @vivek The result of Log is:  _id -1 field1

Comment: @Eman87 c.getColumnName(0) returns the name of First Column of your result set. which is "field1" in this case. So either you are not selecting "_id" in your select query or your table doesn't contains "_id" column. Can you paste select query here?

Comment: public Cursor getTips(String start) {
  // Select All Query
  String query = "SELECT * FROM " + TABLE_TIPS + " LIMIT " + start + ",50";
  Cursor cursor = database.rawQuery(query, null);

  cursor.moveToFirst();
  return cursor;

 }

Comment: I solved it by using c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(c.getColumnName(0))); Thank you so much for your help.

Comment: @Eman87 good to know your problem is solved. "c.getString(0)" would have also served your purpose. Can you add the line Log.v("out-data",DAO.TIP_ID+" "+c.getColumnIndex(DAO.TIP_ID)+" "+c.getColumnName(0)); in the function "getTips()" before return statement? and post the output here?

Answer (score 0):

The query `selection` does not contain the column `DAO.TIP_ID`.

Answer (score 0):

You should fix this to solve this error message

> "Couldn't read row 0, col -1 from CursorWindow.  Make sure the Cursor is initialized correctly before accessing data from it."

it works in my code.

1. Try to position cursor by `moveToFirst` before reading data from it.
2. check for `null`. e,g; `if (c != null && c.moveToFirst()) {}`
3. check for count. e,g; `(c != null && c.getCount() >0 && c.moveToFirst()){}`